# Direct operation on Android SRAM/DRAM

Tags: android, ram

I wanted to ask if there was any possibility for developers on android devices to allocate and apply direct operations (read&write by address) to the following :

- The device's DRAM
- The processor's SRAM

Why I need it : I'm a Ph.D. student in electronics :)

My knowledge of Android development is quite basic, so sorry if it's a basic question.

I do believe this question was not asked. If it isn't the case, I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to write a virus?

Comment: Not really, just want to allocate SRAM or DRAM and perform direct operation in the boundaries of the app's allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least using the API provided by Android.

Android environment is very limitated when you try to make hardware operations, for good reasons. Reading and writting directly in the memory may cause very important security issues, and probably inconsistences decreasing user experience.

On the other hand you could use the NDK to build some C library to embed in your Android application. Until I know libraries in C uses a low level apis of the Android System (A linux is running behind). Maybe you could accomplish your goal in this way.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was not aware that we could do that :)
I will investigate this further :)

Comment: If the answer is valid to you, can I ask you to mark it as valid?, It would be useful to other users, and for me I think I could exchange the points for beer at some point xD